# Defining an array down to a nonzero constant

Tags: arrays, verilog, system-verilog

I have the following sub-module:

```
module test
(
input [LENGTH : 1] array;
);

...

endmodule
```

and I'm calling it from a top module as follows:

```
...
wire [LENGTH-1 : 0] array_top;
test test_i
(
.array (array_top);
);
...
```

Assume `LENGTH` is the same in both modules.

1. How will `array_top` map to `array`, given `array_top` goes down to zero but `array` goes to down 1?
2. Why would anyone define an array down to 1 and not down to 0?
3. What will happen to `array[0]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your questions can be answered with a small testbench:

```
module tb;

reg [3:0] atop;
initial begin
    $monitor("array_top=%b, array=%b", array_top, test_i.array);
    #1 atop = 4'b0000;
    #1 atop = 4'b0001;
    #1 atop = 4'b0010;
    #1 atop = 4'b0100;
end

wire [3:0] array_top = atop;
test test_i (.array (array_top));

endmodule

module test (input [4:1] array);
endmodule
```

Output:

```
array_top=xxxx, array=xxxx
array_top=0000, array=0000
array_top=0001, array=0001
array_top=0010, array=0010
array_top=0100, array=0100
```

1. From your connection: array[1] = array_top[0], etc.
2. Sometimes people want to omit connecting a signal's LSB, like an address for a memory, because the LSB has no effect.
3. There is no `array[0]` signal.

Answer (score 1):

When connecting ports, Verilog only cares that arrays have the same size (called an `equivalent type` in SystemVerilog) It does not care about the starting index value, or whether it increases or decreases. It will start by connecting the right range (LSB) of each signal. In your case `array_top[0]` connects to `array[1]`. If the sizes do not match you may get an error or warning, depending on the tool and its settings. Then the connection will either be padded or truncated after hitting the left range (MSB).